# Is there a way to reset the saved check box values in JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am currently working on a Yahtzee project and while I can get my functions up to now to work. I am having issues with resetting the checked values because even when I reset the game, the checked dice are still saved until I refresh the page. How can I fix this/get this to work?

I have provided my code up till now.

```js
let dice = [{
    'img': "Die1.PNG",
    'value': 1
  },
  {
    'img': "Die2.PNG",
    'value': 2
  },
  {
    'img': "Die3.PNG",
    'value': 3
  },
  {
    'img': "Die4.PNG",
    'value': 4
  },
  {
    'img': "Die5.PNG",
    'value': 5
  },
  {
    'img': "Die6.PNG",
    'value': 6
  }
]

let checkedDice = [{
    'dice': 0,
    'checked': false,
    'id': "die1"
  },
  {
    'dice': 0,
    'checked': false,
    'id': "die2"
  },
  {
    'dice': 0,
    'checked': false,
    'id': "die3"
  },
  {
    'dice': 0,
    'checked': false,
    'id': "die4"
  },
  {
    'dice': 0,
    'checked': false,
    'id': "die5"
  },
  {
    'dice': 0,
    'checked': false,
    'id': "die6"
  },
]

var turns = 9;
var rollsRem = 3;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
const winPoints = 200;

// Function that will roll dice
function roll() {
  if (rollsRem > 0) {

    for (let i = 0; i < checkedDice.length; i++) {
      if (checkedDice[i].checked == false) {
        let rollDice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        document.getElementById(checkedDice[i].id).innerHTML = `<img src="${dice[rollDice].img}" width='45px'>`;
      }
    }
    rollsRem--;
    var display = document.getElementById("rollsRem");
    display.innerHTML = rollsRem;
  } else {
    alert("u gotta do somethin else")
    for (let j = 0; j < checkedDice.length; j++) {
      // userDice[j].checked = false;
      // rollsLeft = 3;
    }
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  reset();

  function reset() {
    roll();
  }

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    alert("reset this");
    rollsRem = 3;
    var display = document.getElementById("rollsRem");
    display.innerHTML = rollsRem;
    roll();
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  });

  $("#cdie1").click(function() {
    checkedDice[0] = !checkedDice[0];
  })
  $("#cdie2").click(function() {
    checkedDice[1] = !checkedDice[1];
  })
  $("#cdie3").click(function() {
    checkedDice[2] = !checkedDice[2];
  })
  $("#cdie4").click(function() {
    checkedDice[3] = !checkedDice[3];
  })
  $("#cdie5").click(function() {
    checkedDice[4] = !checkedDice[4];
  })
  $("#cdie6").click(function() {
    checkedDice[5] = !checkedDice[5];
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header";
  background-color: black;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}

header {
  background: black;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f80000;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #f80000;
  color: black;
}

th,
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: white;
}

#scoreCard {
  right: 500px;
  top: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 300px;
}

#yourRoll {
  color: white;
}

div h2 img {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

<script>
</script>


<div class="container">

  <header id="pageHeader">
    <h1> <img src="yahtzee.jpg" width="100px"> YAHTZEE </h1>
  </header>

  <ul class="nav nav-pills red">
    <li class="active"><a href="https://usbrandcolors.com/oracle-colors/" target="_blank"> Color Scheme </a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <table id="scoreCard">
          <br>
          <br>
          <span style="color:white;"> <strong> SCORE BOARD </strong> </span>
          <br>
          <tr>
            <th> Win Points </th>
            <th> 200</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> Wins </td>
            <td> 0 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> Losses </td>
            <td> 0 </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Upper Section</th>
            <th>How to Score</th>
            <th>Game #1</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> ACE <img src="Die1.PNG" width="45px"> = 1 </td>
            <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY ACES </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> TWOS <img src="Die2.PNG" width="45px"> = 2 </td>
            <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY TWOS </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> THREES <img src="Die3.PNG" width="45px"> = 3</td>
            <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY THREES</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> FOURS <img src="Die4.PNG" width="45px"> = 4 </td>
            <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY FOURS </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> FIVES <img src="Die5.PNG" width="45px"> = 5</td>
            <td>COUNT AND ADD ONLY FIVES</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> SIXES <img src="Die6.PNG" width="45px"> = 6 </td>
            <td> COUNT AND ADD ONLY SIXES </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> 3 OF A KIND </td>
            <td> ADD TOTAL OF ALL DICE </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> 4 OF A KIND </td>
            <td> ADD TOTAL OF ALL DICE </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> FULL HOUSE </td>
            <td> SCORE 25 </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 30px"> TOTAL SCORE </td>
            <td> <img src="whitearrow.png" width="100px"> </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 30px"> BONUS w/ total score </td>
            <td style="font-size: 30px"> SCORE 35 </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 30px"> TOTAL </td>
            <td> <img src="whitearrow.png" width="100px"> </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="yourRoll" class="col-sm">
        <h2 style="color: white"> Your Roll </h2>
        <div id="die1">
          <img src="Die1.PNG" width="45px">
        </div>
        Die 1 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie1" />
        <div id="die2">
          <img src="Die2.PNG" width="45px">
        </div>
        Die 2 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie2" />
        <div id="die3">
          <img src="Die3.PNG" width="45px">
        </div>
        Die 3 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie3" />
        <div id="die4">
          <img src="Die4.PNG" width="45px">
        </div>
        Die 4 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie4" />
        <div id="die5">
          <img src="Die5.PNG" width="45px">
        </div>
        Die 5 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie5" />
        <div id="die6">
          <img src="Die6.PNG" width="45px">
        </div>
        Die 6 <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="cdie6" />
        <br>
        <div>
          </br>
          <!--                    TODO: Fix the Rolls Left Counter        -->
          <p> Rolls Left: <span id="rollsRem"> 2 </span></p>
          </br>
          <button type="button" id="rollbutt" onclick="roll();" style="color: black"> Roll Button </button>
          </br>
          <button style="color: black" type="button" id="reset"> Reset </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a `reset` button type ... `<button type="reset">Reset</reset>`

Comment: I agree with @PeterSeliger. Just don't forget to add a form element around your inputs to make reset know which form values it's clearing.

Comment: Nope nothing, what about resetting those checked boxed values back to their defaults?

Answer (score -1):

use "autocomplete" attribute to avoid saved states after page refreshing

```
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
```